# Convert and plot date and time with pandas or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date

Trying to plot date and time using pandas. 'dt' and 'quality'

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib
    import seaborn as sns
    %matplotlib inline

    data = pd.read_csv('pontina_FCD.csv')
```

[image: data sample]

I've tried lots of options about transfer date, but sill facing the error.

Comment: please post your data in a machine readable format

Answer (score 0):

`Pandas` has methods that support plotting.

Can you try the following:

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data['dt'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
data['quality'].plot()
plot.show()
```